# Что означает width в PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

подскажите, что в PyAudio означает "width"? У меня width=2, channels=2, chunk=1024. Длина len(data)=2*2*1024=4096. 
Как разделить "data" так, чтобы получить данные для левого канала. Пробовал брать первую половину - не верно (появляются шумы). 
Может брать две ячейки через две (1,2, 5,6, 9,10) ? 
В документации видел, что width может принимать значения 1, 2, 3 или 4 байта.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я не совсем представляю о чем вы написали, 
но мне попадался пример, который может быть вам полезен (мне так кажется).

Источник здесь: https://gist.github.com/tam17aki/44e544d8d6d07e31de764bbd28fdee40

```
# ...возможность изменить высоту и формат с помощью ползунка PyQt5.

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QSlider, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import pyworld as pw         # pip install pyworld


sample_rate        = 16000
input_buffer_size  = 1024 * 8
output_buffer_size = 1024 * 2
f0_rate = 1.0  # Регулировка высоты голоса: удвоение на одну октаву вверх на 0,5 вверх на одну октаву вниз
sp_rate = 1.0  # Регулировка цвета голоса (> 0,0): для женских голосов меньше 1,0, для мужчин верно обратное


class Analysis_Synthesis(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.CHUNK = input_buffer_size   # Ширина данных голосового чтения за один раз
        self.RATE  = sample_rate         # Частота дискретизации
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream_in = self.audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                         channels=1,
                                         rate=self.RATE,
                                         input=True,
                                         output=True,
                                         frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)

        self.stream_out = self.audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                          channels=1,
                                          rate=self.RATE,
                                          output=True,
                                          frames_per_buffer=output_buffer_size)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(5)

        self.f0_rate = f0_rate
        self.sp_rate = sp_rate

        # Место хранения голосовых данных (данные графика)
        self.data = np.zeros(self.CHUNK)

        self.initUI()

    def analysis_resynthesis(self, signal):
        f0, t = pw.dio(signal, sample_rate)            # Извлечение основной частоты
        f0 = pw.stonemask(signal, f0, t, sample_rate)  # утонченность
        sp = pw.cheaptrick(signal, f0, t, sample_rate) # Извлечение спектральной огибающей
        ap = pw.d4c(signal, f0, t, sample_rate)        # Извлечение индекса апериодичности

        # Сдвиг высоты тона
        modified_f0 = self.f0_rate * f0

        # Сдвиг форманты (равномерное расширение и сжатие оси частот)
        modified_sp = np.zeros_like(sp)
        sp_range    = int(modified_sp.shape[1] * self.sp_rate)
        for f in range(modified_sp.shape[1]):
            if (f < sp_range):
                if self.sp_rate >= 1.0:
                    modified_sp[:, f] = sp[:, int(f / self.sp_rate)]
                else:
                    modified_sp[:, f] = sp[:, int(self.sp_rate * f)]
            else:
                modified_sp[:, f] = sp[:, f]

        synth = pw.synthesize(modified_f0, modified_sp, ap, sample_rate)

        return synth.astype(np.int16).tobytes()

    def update(self):
        try:
            audio_input = self.stream_in.read(
                self.CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
            signal = np.frombuffer(
                audio_input, dtype='int16').astype(np.float64)
            output = self.analysis_resynthesis(signal)
            self.stream_out.write(output)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nInterrupt.")
            self.stream_in.stop_stream()
            self.stream_in.close()
            self.stream_out.stop_stream()
            self.stream_out.close()
            self.audio.terminate()
            print("Stop Streaming.")

    def initUI(self):

        # Создать вертикальный слайдер
        sld_f0 = QSlider(Qt.Vertical, self)
        # Предотвратить слайдер от фокусировки
        sld_f0.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        sld_f0.setGeometry(30, 40, 30, 200)
        # Функция ChangeValue вызывается при перемещении ползунка
        sld_f0.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue_f0)

        # Создать вертикальный слайдер
        sld_sp = QSlider(Qt.Vertical, self)
        # Предотвратить слайдер от фокусировки
        sld_sp.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        sld_sp.setGeometry(130, 40, 30, 200)
        # Функция ChangeValue вызывается при перемещении ползунка
        sld_sp.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue_sp)

        # Создание метки (класс для отображения символов)
        self.label_f0 = QLabel(self)
        # Положение метки (x, y, ширина, высота)
        self.label_f0.setGeometry(30, 0, 100, 40)
        self.label_f0.setText(
            'Pitch\n' + str(int(self.f0_rate * 100)) + '%')

        # Создание метки (класс для отображения символов)
        self.label_sp = QLabel(self)
        # Положение метки (x, y, ширина, высота)
        self.label_sp.setGeometry(120, 0, 100, 40)
        self.label_sp.setText('Formant\n' + str(int(self.sp_rate * 100)) + '%')

        sld_f0.setValue(25)
        sld_sp.setValue(20)

        # Размер окна
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Voice Changer')
        self.show()

    def changeValue_f0(self, value):
        self.f0_rate = (50 + 2.0 * value) / 100
        self.label_f0.setText('Pitch\n' + str(int(self.f0_rate * 100)) + '%')

    def changeValue_sp(self, value):
        self.sp_rate = (75 + 1.25 * value) / 100
        self.label_sp.setText('Formant\n' + str(int(self.sp_rate * 100)) + '%')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Analysis_Synthesis()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь я разместил более подробный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887163/how-to-get-data-of-each-channel-in-pyaudio но т.к. никто не отвечает, решил сузить задачу